# Find when a particular place in memory is changed in c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Let's say I have an object `MyObject` and it has an attribute `double MyObject::a`. When I initialize `a` I set it to `0.05`, but at some point when I run my code I notice that `a` is `1.something e-316`, even though my code is never supposed to change its value. If I knew an exact place in memory that `a` occupies, is there a tool that will tell me when exactly this place is overwritten?

Comment: Maybe, but probably your most practical option is to step though the code using your debugger and monitor the value.

Comment: Some debuggers have breakpoint on memory change option.

Comment: @john using debugger I can easily stop *at a particular* point to check if `a` has changed. But I don't see how that helps me finding out when exactly its value was changed

Comment: @user4581301 do you have an example?

Comment: VS2022's debugger has a break on change feature.

Comment: This problem could be caused by UB. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @jabaa unfortunately, coming up with one would be as easy as finding why exactly is the value of `a` changed, which is my goal after all

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, gdb, lldb and the Visual Studio debugger can all do this, I find it extremely useful sometimes.

Comment: @Ilya Use the debugger to narrow down when the value changes. Step though your code at a high level until you see it change. Then repeat the process at a lower level. Rinse and repeat. It doesn't take long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already noted, you could use a debugger for this. Most reasonably recent debuggers have some capability to break when a value is written to a particular variable (e.g., Visual Studio calls this a "watchpoint" or "data breakpoint" (depending on what age of IDE you're looking at), if memory serves.

Depending on the situation, you *might* be able to get some useful information by changing your `double` to a `const double`:

`const double value { 0.05 };`

Then any code that tries to assign a new value to this variable simply won't compile.

If, however, the problem arises from some code doing an out of bounds write, rather than assigning to the value that's getting overwritten, this won't help find that.

[gdb watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)
[VS data breakpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022#BKMK_set_a_data_breakpoint_native_cplusplus_only)

Comment: thanks, I have not heard about gdb watchpoints before